# How to force pipelining

Tags: ajax, http, firefox, google-chrome

Is there any way to tell modern browsers
to use http pipelining for my ajax requests?

P.S.: as I understand currently only opera uses
http 1.1 pipelining by default but firefox and chrome
need to be configured in special way for that

Comment: Why ? If you use a standard http server, you should let it negotiate with the browsers the most efficient solution, which depends on their capabilities. Most browsers don't support it except as experimental feature. The question is *why* you want to force it.

Comment: because I'm using browser as bosh xmpp client and pipelining gives network performance gain in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way across browsers to do this (I assume you are talking about doing this in your Javascript code). [The Wikipedia article on HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) seems to explain it pretty well.

There is also no means in the HTTP protocol to request that a client implement pipelining.